# How to update UI from background state

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I'm trying to create a timer app. I have a singleton class with a Timer which fires every x minutes. Using custom delegate I pass the data to active view controller and update the value in a label. If the data is when the count is y, I perform push and update the count in another view controller's label.

When application is in foreground I didn't get any problem. If the application is in background state the counter keeps running and label text isn't updated and push isn't performed. Still I'm in first view controller. How to solve this?

Comment: why do you need to do anything to the UI when the user is not using the app in the foreground? You can keep the timer running without touching UI.

Comment: @JeffreyChang But when the user comeback after y minutes, he should see second view controller. Not first view controller.

Comment: Then make a check when the application comes back and take them to the second view controller.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez So iOS don't allow this? But it keeps updating even in background state when device is connected with Xcode. After I unplug the device from Xcode It is not updating.

Comment: when device is connected to Xcode, it could be in debug mode, and it will stay alive in background as long as app is connected to Xcode. In general apps don't last long in background. You should use app delegate methods to check when your app comes to foeground

Comment: update your UI at viewDidAppear. you can check your timer and then update your UI accordingly.

Comment: please edit your question to show your timer code; essentially you need to determine what is the `Date` at which the second screen should be shown.  When your app returns to the foreground you need to determine if that date has been reached and if so, show the second screen.  You don't need to do anything in the background or while your app is suspended.

Answer (score -2):

like I mentioned in your comment section. when you app is in the background state you shouldn't continuously updating your UI as it is pointless. when user tapped back into your app your view controller will call a function `viewDidAppear(animated)`. In that function you can check timer condition then present second view controller if needed. I'll post a sample code below

```
class FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    var timerExpiration = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if timerExpiration {
            let vc = SecondViewController()
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to wrap all foreground UI tasks in a block like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // do your UI stuff here, like
   // label.text = "Main thread stuff"
}
```

Put this in your timer action.